# Authenticate with sudo on a crontab job

Tags: python, cron

I have a call to a python script that is `sudo -u user_name python python_scipt.py` and I need to schedule it to run every 30 minutes with crontab. The problem is how can I authenticate it with sudo on crontab?

Comment: Can you just `sudo crontab -u username -e` and add that script directly from the desired account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything solved with the `sudo crontab -u username -e`

credits to 9000